# iOS CoreBluetooth peripheral not discovering my custom vendor service

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am writing an iOS app, as well as programming a `BLE113` bluetooth peripheral and I am having trouble getting my iOS app to discover services on the bluetooth peripheral that I have defined myself.

These are two services defined in `gatt.xml`:

```
<service uuid="1802" advertise="true" >
    <description>Immediate Alert Service</description>
    <characteristic uuid="2a06">
        <properties write_no_response="true" />
        <value length="1" />
    </characteristic>
</service>

<service uuid="95643131-7088-492b-8038-423cdb422659" advertise="true" type="primary">
    <description>Test Service</description>
    <characteristic uuid="6864d681-06ea-4cbf-b49b-81299ac2f572" id="my_data">
        <properties write="true" indicate="true" />
        <value length="1"/>
    </characteristic>
</service>
```

Once the central manager is in "`CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`" I can use a switch in the app to scan for peripherals in my iOS app which have a service with the "`Test Service`" `UUID`:

```
NSString *myUUID = @"95643131-7088-492b-8038-423cdb422659";
NSArray *services = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [CBUUID UUIDWithString:myUUID],
     nil];
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
```

The peripheral will be found, and it will connect. However, when I try to discover services on the peripheral:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
    self.connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.connected);
}
```

It will only discover "Immediate Alert Service", which is a Bluetooth `SIG` service, and will not discover any if I only try to discover services with the "`Test Service`" `UUID` by calling:

```
NSString *myUUID = @"95643131-7088-492b-8038-423cdb422659";
NSArray *services = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [CBUUID UUIDWithString:myUUID],
                     nil];
[peripheral discoverServices:services];
```

When using a "`BLE Scanner`" app I downloaded to the iPad I am using, it will discover the peripheral and the service I defined, and they are also both visible when using the `BLEGUI` tool so I assume that the service is advertising correctly. Is there a certain way I'm supposed to attempt to discover vendor specific services? I am new to both Objective-C and `BGScript` so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you keep reference of the `peripheral` found (`@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *connectedPeripheral;`)? I don't remember but I think that your services in String should be uppercase. Check the value of `[CBUUID UUIDWithString:myUUID]` and with `discoverServices:nil` is the characteristics UUID is in uppercase too.

Comment: Yes I keep a CBPeripheral *myPeripheral in the class which is set when the peripheral connects. 

When the UUID strings are converted to a CBUUID type they are put into uppercase. Could the fact that they are not uppercase in my gatt.xml file be a problem?

Comment: You can try using another iOS device running `CBPeripheralManager` advertising some services. This will let you know if your iOS code is working properly or not. From there you may need to look into issues with your peripheral configuration.